# Realtime hologram pyramid

Tags: camera

I'd like to make a hologram pyramid project and I'd like it to work in realtime using blender game engine. I need help to set up the 3 cameras to work simultaniously, can anybody help me?

Comment: Why do you need 3 cameras?